# Is it possible to web scrape an Android app through an emulator on PC, using Watir with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

So I know that was a mouthful, so to expand a bit I'm hoping to get text data from an Android app. I've read a little that I would need an Android emulator on my PC to do so. But I have no idea how to use Watir (the current web scraper I've been using successfully) to scrape data from an emulator.

Comment: You can't use a web scraper to extract data from something not-web.

Comment: That's not true. Appium will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use to interact with a native mobile application is Appium. There is a Ruby binding for Appium that you can use. There is currently not a Watir API for Appium, though it is on our list of possible things we can work on at our [hackathon](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/ruby-open-source-testing-code-hackathon-tickets-36985700225) in a few weeks. Keep a watch on our [Watir blog](http://watir.com/blog/) to see if we end up able to implement something.